# How to add many2one field in a file as data.xml file odoo 12

Tags: odoo

ive create a new category named x in the field category(categ_id) under the model product.template i want to load in to data.xml,How can i achieve this?

EDIT

I've tried like this and added data file in the manifest ,and i tried running in diffrent database but it doesnt show up,my xml code is below:

```xml
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="product_category_all" model="product.category">
            <field name="name">All</field>
        </record>

        <record id="product_category_1" model="product.category">
            <field name="parent_id" ref="product_category_all"/>
            <field name="name">MEDICINES</field>
            <field name="complete_name">All / MEDICINES</field>
        </record>
        <record id="product_category_2" model="product.category">
            <field name="parent_id" ref="product_category_all"/>
            <field name="name">LAB TEST</field>
            <field name="complete_name">All / LAB TEST</field>
        </record>
        <record id="product_category_3" model="product.category">
            <field name="parent_id" ref="product_category_all"/>
            <field name="name">Vaccine</field>
            <field name="complete_name">All / Vaccine</field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add the new category, you need to create a new `product.category` record.

There is an example in the product data file which defines two categories `Saleable` and `Expenses` as sub-categories of `All` category:

```xml
<record id="product_category_all" model="product.category">
    <field name="name">All</field>
</record>
<record id="product_category_1" model="product.category">
    <field name="parent_id" ref="product_category_all"/>
    <field name="name">Saleable</field>
</record>
<record id="cat_expense" model="product.category">
    <field name="parent_id" ref="product_category_all"/>
    <field name="name">Expenses</field>
</record>
```

***Edit:***

You can find at the Odoo [Data Files](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/data.html#field) documentation that the `ref` attribute is used to provide the value of many2one fields using a valid [external id](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/glossary.html#term-external-id).

`All` category is declared in the product data file using `product_category_all` as an id.  the external id should be:

```
product.product_category_all
```

`complete_name` is a computed char field with `store` set to `True`, its value should be computed and returned when requested then stored in the database.

You need to change the `parent_id` field definition and remove the `complete_name` field.

***Example:***

```
<record id="product_category_1" model="product.category">
    <field name="parent_id" ref="product.product_category_all"/>
    <field name="name">MEDICINES</field>
</record>
<record id="product_category_2" model="product.category">
    <field name="parent_id" ref="product.product_category_all"/>
    <field name="name">LAB TEST</field>
</record>
<record id="product_category_3" model="product.category">
    <field name="parent_id" ref="product.product_category_all"/>
    <field name="name">Vaccine</field>
</record>
```

Comment: My first example is valid under `product` module, check my edit.

Comment: yes,ive sorted it now,thanks kenly.You got youtube channel or anything?

Comment: No, I am only on StackOverflow.